# quotation marks in PHP

Tags: php, html, echo

How to properly/correctly display this using quotes? I'd like to display only the value

Here's the image:
[image]

```
echo '
        <form method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Basic Pay</label>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <input name="basic_salary" type="text" class="form-control" value="₱ '
        . number_format($basic_salary, 2, '.', ', ') . ' disabled />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question. It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo '<form method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Basic Pay</label>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <input name="basic_salary" type="text" class="form-control" value="₱ '. number_format($basic_salary, 2, ".", ", ") . '" disabled />
        </div>
    </div>';
```